# How to add contextual classes in Yii 2 ActiveField / ActiveForm?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, yii2

In Bootstrap 3 we can add a contextual class to a `form-group` container which will color that form field container in a specific color, ie. `has-error` will render it reddish:

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
    <label for="field">Erroneous label</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Erroneous input" id="field" />
    <p class="help-block">Erroneous help-block</p>
</div>
```

Label, the input's text color and border and final `p.help-block` will all become red.

In Yii 2 we can use `ActiveForm` and `ActiveField` to do the same in one-liner:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'field')
    ->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Erroneous input'])
    ->label('Erroneous label')
    ->hint('Dummy hint') ?>
```

And it generates roughly the same markup as above, in a `form-group` container.

I have gone [through the docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield) and didn't find a way to add a `has-error` class to the `form-group` container.

- [$hintOptions](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#$hintOptions-detail)
- [$inputOptions](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#$inputOptions-detail)
- [$labelOptions](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#$labelOptions-detail)

Do not work for this scenario.

Comment: if you want a custom class other than `has-error` you can use the `errorCssClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii automatically adds `has-error` class in case of validation errors. 
If you want to add any CSS-class to ActiveField container then you can use [options](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#$options-detail) property. For example:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'field', [
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'form-group has-error',
        ],
    ])
    ->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Erroneous input'])
    ->label('Erroneous label')
    ->hint('Dummy hint');
?>
```

Comment: Great! I have made a small change to your answer (you've forgot to add `class` property in the `options`. It works now and I will accept your answer.